# SQL Query join two tables based on column that was parsed

Tags: sql-server

I have outputs I wish to join based on column, but problem is, one of the columns was parsed and then created via the statement

```
PARSENAME(
   REPLACE(
      replace(
        replace(
          replace(
             replace(dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name,'My Company\',''),
          '-VLAN2','')
        ,'.VLAN2\','')
      ,'.Instr\','') 
  , '\' , '.')
,1)
```

which outputs

```
abc
123
abra
cadabra
```

The other table has columns directly printed as

```
abc
123
abra
cadabra
```

I am trying to turn this:

```
abc      wine
123      sherry
abra     cognac
cadabra  whisky
```

and this

```
abc       Alaska       Bobby
123       Canada       Jessie
abra      New Zealand  Audrey
cadabra   Maldives     Sammy
```

**Into this:**

```
abc      wine    Alaska       Bobby
123      sherry  Canada       Jessie
abra     cognac  New Zealand  Audrey
cadabra  whisky  Maldives     Sammy
```

And remember, the first column one of the the tables was artificially created with `PARSENAME`

Query for first output

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name,'My Company\',''),'-VLAN2',''),'.VLAN2\',''),'.Instr\','') , '\' , '.'),1) as "Site",
                   Count (CASE
                            WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '11.%' THEN 1
                          END) AS 'SEP-11',
                   Count(CASE
                            WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '12.%' THEN 1
                          END) AS 'SEP-12'...
            FROM   dbo.sem_computer
                   INNER JOIN [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
                           ON [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID ...
            WHERE dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name NOT LIKE '%Servers%'
      Group by PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name,'My Company\',''),'-VLAN2',''),'.VLAN2\',''),'.Instr\','') , '\' , '.'),1)
      Order by "Site" DESC
```

Query for second output

```
SELECT * from dbo.SEPM_Site
```

I created dbo.SEPM_Site, and the column to join is actually a primary Key!

[image]

Comment: Can you show the query you have right now?

Comment: @Leptonator I added it to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking of a version of sql server after 2005, in order to make some sense on what you have you can put the query into a CTE and join it with a table like:

```
;with cte as (
  --- put the parsename query here (without the order by)
)
select 
  *  -- feel free to query what you need from here
from cte
join SEPM_Site ss
  on cte.Site = ss.Site
```

Comment: This is SQL 2012, will try this

Comment: This works. Ironically if `select *`, it executes at lightening speed, but because it displays duplicate columns, `site` twice, I try to select one column, i.e. `select rackcode` and it's taking forever to execute. Any suggestions on how to select all columns of SEPM_site `EXCEPT` for one column, i.e. `site`?

Comment: It's difficult to say why this would happen. Try checking the 2 plans for differences.

Comment: I posted new question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969640/sql-2012-exclude-column