# SQL Server 2012, exclude column

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have SQL query

```
; with cte as 
(
   SELECT 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name, 'My Company\', ''), '-VLAN2', ''), '.VLAN2\', ''), '.Instr\', '') , '\' , '.'), 1) as "Site",
       Count (CASE
                 WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '11.%' THEN 1
              END) AS 'SEP-11',
       Count (CASE
                 WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '12.%' THEN 1
              END) AS 'SEP-12',
   FROM   
       dbo.sem_computer
   INNER JOIN 
       [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER] ON [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
   WHERE 
       dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name NOT LIKE '%Servers%'
   GROUP BY 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(dbo.IDENTITY_MAP.Name,'My Company\',''),'-VLAN2',''),'.VLAN2\',''),'.Instr\','') , '\' , '.'),1)
)
select *
from cte
join SEPM_site ss on cte.Site = ss.Site
```

That gives output I am looking for ------ almost i.e.

```
Site  SEP-11  SEP-12 Rackcode  Circuit  Site
```

I only need one column for `Site`.

I tried recreating a temporary table with the columns, and dropping it, i.e.

```
; with cte as (SELECT ...)
select * into temptable
from cte
join SEPM_site ss
 on cte.Site = ss.Site
alter table temptable
drop column cte.Site
select * from temptable
drop table temptable
```

But I get error

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

And if I don't specify which table `Site` is from, I get error,

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Site' in table 'temptable' is specified more than once.

But that's why I am trying to remove duplicate column!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want in your select statement:

```
select cte.Site, cte.[SEP-11], cte.[SEP-12], ss.Rackcode, ss.Circuit
from cte
join SEPM_site ss
 on cte.Site = ss.Site
```

You can also select all columns in cte and just the ones you want in ss:

```
select cte.*, ss.Rackcode, ss.Circuit
from cte
join SEPM_site ss
 on cte.Site = ss.Site
```